# Visio Foreign Key

Tags: ms-office, visio, erd

I am designing a Entity relationship diagram using Microsoft Visio 2010 and using Database Model Diagram.

I have 2 tables, Student table which has Student ID (Primary key) and Course ID (should be foreign key) and i have a Course table which has Course ID (Primary key). My problem is i can not link the course ID in the course table to the course id in the student table as a many to one relationship. Each time i do it, the student id displays in the course table and it automatically makes that a foreign key.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How I miss ERD's, Did them at Uni last year.... does your model not work, if you remove the course code from "student"? will it still not read as a 1:m----- 1 course CAN HOLD many students.........else it would just be a 1:1 1 student TO ATTEND 1 course

Does that make sense?? I know how I am trying to explain it....if it doesn't help I will try print screen my ERD from last year to help you later today/tonight.

Comment: It's ok now. I have managed to do it another way. Thanks a lot for your help though :)